# Why MathNet Point3D components are ReadOnly?

Tags: mathnet-numerics

Does anyone knows why the Components X, Y and Z of a MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean.Ponit3D are readonly doubles?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand from this [link](https://spatial.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Spatial.Euclidean/Point3D.htm) `Point3D` is a ValueType/Struct, not a reference type class. 
Now because of this i suspect that you would have to re-assign the whole object instead of trying to modify its components separately. Think of it like ( loosely ) a primitive value